# Can I batch-rename a tag?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I'm able to retag questions on SO. I've just noticed that there exist a [push-notification](/questions/tagged/push-notification) tag with 1700+ questions and then a [push-notifications](/questions/tagged/push-notifications) (plural) with some 30 questions.

My thought is that those 30 questions should be retagged to the most common singular tag, and then the plural tag should be canceled.

Is there a way I can do this, with my SO reputation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I merged the plural into the singular and created a synonym to keep it from coming back. It's not uncommon for the plural of a tag to creep in. The best thing to do is what you've done, which is open a request for it here when you see these creep up from time to time.

Comment: *merge*! That was the verb I was missing! :)

Answer (score 0):

> Can I batch-rename a tag?

No, for regular Stack Overflow users this is not possible. You'll have to manually edit (or re-tag) each post.

> then the plural tag should be canceled

A tag with no posts automatically gets removed in 24 - 36 hours.

Comment: thanks for your feedback, I didn't know that

Answer (score -1):

A diamond moderator can merge those tags, so you don't need to do that manually. This seems to be a simple case where nothing more than merging is needed.

Comment: Well, since the plural saw a bit of use, I created a synonym to keep it from creeping back in.